How to use the ubuntu24.04 LTSC's remote login function?
I am a White programmer. And I have two computer, one Windows10 and one ubunt24.04LTSC. For the convenience of work, I want to use Windows10 to remotely login ubuntu24.04. As it happens, I noticed ubuntu's new remote login feature.
When I use it, an error occurs.
Here's how I do it:

Ubuntu24.04: go to the system set, open the remote login, set hostname、username and password. then, I log out my user.

In the windows10, use the mstsc to remote.
the picture of remotely connected


It is happy that, I connect the ubuntu24 successfully. But when I entered the password to log in, I could see the ubuntu mouse pointer, and the screen was black, and I couldn't see any desktop content.
The same thing happened when I used another piece of software "mobaXterm" to log in on port 3389.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
